# iOS [MarketingCloudSDKFoundation(ClientData) sfmc_setAttributeNamed:value:]_block_invoke crash

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

We're experiencing crash from `com.salesforce.marketingcloud.marketingcloudsdk.foundation.registration` thread. Seems like it happens, when main thread calls `sfmc_setPushEnabled`.

Did anyone experience this too? It happens for a small amount of users and we can't reproduce it.

SDK version: 8.1.0 ([GitHub](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/releases/tag/v8.1.0))

Thanks!

Stack traces:

```
Crashed: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.marketingcloudsdk.foundation.registration

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000006e80a7c20

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3670 objc_retain + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1a70cc <redacted> + 208
2  CoreFoundation                 0xc2bb8 <redacted> + 32
3  CoreFoundation                 0x47408 <redacted> + 140
4  MarketingCloudSDK              0x5d434 __72-[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation(ClientData) sfmc_setAttributeNamed:value:]_block_invoke + 2104
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac <redacted> + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x13428 <redacted> + 56
7  MarketingCloudSDK              0x5cb78 -[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation(ClientData) sfmc_setAttributeNamed:value:] + 220
8  MarketingCloudSDK              0x10530 -[MobilePushSDK sfmc_setAttributeNamed:value:] + 88
9  MarketingCloudSDK              0x21768 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 + 656
10 MarketingCloudSDK              0x21b60 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_0 + 1672
11 MarketingCloudSDK              0x19354 -[MarketingCloudSDKConfig .cxx_destruct] + 16512
12 MarketingCloudSDK              0x1978c -[MarketingCloudSDKConfig .cxx_destruct] + 17592
13 Foundation                     0x7af50 <redacted> + 16
14 Foundation                     0x3c478 <redacted> + 708
15 Foundation                     0x3c1ac <redacted> + 16
16 Foundation                     0x4183c <redacted> + 172
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x12fc4 <redacted> + 148
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac <redacted> + 20
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x7330 <redacted> + 504
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x6998 <redacted> + 584
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x15944 <redacted> + 396
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x16158 <redacted> + 164
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xda0 _pthread_wqthread + 228
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb7c start_wqthread + 8
```

```
com.apple.main-thread

0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x11fc kevent_id + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x26e58 <redacted> + 228
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x2781c <redacted> + 436
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x136f8 <redacted> + 340
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x132c0 <redacted> + 148
5  MarketingCloudSDK              0x53c3c -[MarketingCloudSDKFoundation setPushEnabledDeveloper:] + 140
6  MarketingCloudSDK              0x119d0 -[MobilePushSDK sfmc_setPushEnabled:] + 408
7  MarketingCloudSDK              0x16e4c -[MarketingCloudSDKConfig .cxx_destruct] + 7032
8  SFMCSDK                        0x2f7f0 block_destroy_helper + 11420
9  App                            0xdfc20 specialized MarketingCloudSDK.setPushEnabled(_:) + 92 (MarketingCloudSDK+MarketingPushNotificationSDKProtocol.swift:92)
10 App                            0x6e4d24 MarketingPushNotificationManager.currentUserUpdateDetected() + 82 (MarketingPushNotificationManager.swift:82)
11 App                            0x6e4f24 @objc MarketingPushNotificationManager.currentUserUpdateDetected() + 4371336996 (<compiler-generated>:4371336996)
12 CoreFoundation                 0x37520 <redacted> + 148
13 CoreFoundation                 0xdb7cc <redacted> + 88
14 CoreFoundation                 0xbe85c <redacted> + 440
15 CoreFoundation                 0x4ba8c _CFXNotificationPost + 700
16 App                            0xee97e0 protocol witness for NotificationCenterProtocol.post(_:) in conformance NSNotificationCenter + 4379744224 (<compiler-generated>:4379744224)
17 App                            0xcb66b4 closure #1 in closure #3 in Users.getCurrent(notificationCenter:) + 357 (Users.swift:357)
18 App                            0xc6b4f0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4377130224 (<compiler-generated>:4377130224)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x2320 <redacted> + 32
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac <redacted> + 20
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x126a4 <redacted> + 928
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x122f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
23 CoreFoundation                 0x98bb8 <redacted> + 16
24 CoreFoundation                 0x7a4f0 <redacted> + 1992
25 CoreFoundation                 0x7f37c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
26 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal + 164
27 UIKitCore                      0x39cf58 <redacted> + 888
28 UIKitCore                      0x39cbbc UIApplicationMain + 340
29 App                            0x1013c main + 13 (main.swift:13)
30 ???                            0x1bbee4dec (Missing)
```